# How to quickly share big data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, performance, memory, multiprocessing

I want to share a large amount of numpy data between different processes, and may also process the data. Currently, I am using a multiprocessing RawArray, but it is still not fast enough. Are there any libraries or methods to improve speed?

```
class ArrayOpe(object):
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array
        self.point = 0
        self.size = len(array)
        self.lock = None

    def reset(self):
        self.point = 0

    @classmethod
    def allocMemArr(cls, row_count, unit_size, t=1):
        if (t == 1):
            li = []
            for i in range(row_count):
                data = sharedctypes.RawArray(ctypes.c_char, unit_size)  # _numpy_to_ctypes[array.dtype.type],
                li.append(data)
            return li
        else:
            print("alloc:", unit_size * row_count)
            data = sharedctypes.RawArray(ctypes.c_char, unit_size * row_count)
            return data

    def getInnerArr(self, point):
        return self.array

    def allocInnerArr(self, size):
        if (self.type == 1):
            self.point += 1
            if (self.point == self.size):
                self.point = 0
            return self.array[self.point], self.point, 0, size
        else:
            if (self.point + size >= self.size):
                self.point = 0
            begin = self.point
            self.point += size

            return self.array, -1, begin, self.point

    def getArray(self, point, begin, end):
        obj = self.getInnerArr(point)
        res = np.frombuffer(obj, dtype=np.uint8, count=end - begin, offset=begin)
        return res

    def getImage(self, point, begin, end, width, height, channel=3):
        arr = self.getArray(point, begin, end)
        arr = arr.reshape(height, width, channel)
        return arr

    # lock
    def setImage(self, image):
        if (self.lock is None):
            self.lock = threading.Lock()
        with self.lock:  # .acquire()
            arr = image.reshape((-1,))
            data, point, begin, end = self.allocInnerArr(len(arr))
            p = ctypes.byref(data, begin)
            ctypes.memmove(p, image.ctypes.data, end - begin)
            return point, begin, end
```

Now I use RawArray to allocate shared memory, and use getImage and setImage to save and load images

I am looking for faster ways to save and load large amounts of image data

Comment: https://superfastpython.com/numpy-share-array-processes/

Comment: A numpy array using `sharedctypes.RawArray` is going to be about as fast as you can get to transfer data between processes (should be similar speed to `sharedmemory`). Are you sure the read/write of the array is the slow part? Have you profiled your code? Sometimes the true cause of bottlenecks are not intuitive, so profiling is very important.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to analyze the bottleneck of this code, and the time-consuming area is ctypes. memove(). However, this is a relatively low-level function, and I cannot optimize it anymore. I have also tried methods such as mmap and SharedMemory, but they are slower. In the native Python field, there may not be any other method that is faster, so I am trying to find other libraries

Comment: `and the time-consuming area is ctypes.memove()` That seems quite strange. Theoretically, np.frombuffer shouldn't need to copy from the raw array, nor should shared memory require any copies. I can't imagine why it would be spending any time in memmove.

Comment: @NickODell:My description is not clear enough. SetImage is a processed numpy array obtained from a certain process and passed into shared memory. As time increases, the time consumed by ctypes. memmove also increases. I don't understand why the time consumption increases